# How to create an index for consecutive and non-consecutive days

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large data.frame structured as:

```
date    torn_count  torn_dpi
31-12-2014  1   0.001
28-12-2014  3   0.003
27-12-2014  1   0.001
22-12-2014  1   0.001
21-12-2014  1   0.001
20-12-2014  1   0.001
19-12-2014  1   0.001
18-12-2014  1   0.001
17-12-2014  3   0.003
15-12-2014  2   0.002
14-12-2014  1   0.001
13-12-2014  1   0.002
11-12-2014  5   0.104
10-12-2014  3   0.003
09-12-2014  1   0.001
08-12-2014  5   0.104
01-12-2014  5   0.014
30-11-2014  2   0.002
29-11-2014  1   0.001
26-11-2014  1   0.001
25-11-2014  2   0.045
24-11-2014  2   1.83
```

I am trying to add an index that has the same value over consecutive days and is increasing over non-consecutive days. Something like:

```
date    torn_count  torn_dpi    index
31/12/2014  1   0.001   1
28/12/2014  3   0.003   2
27/12/2014  1   0.001   2
22/12/2014  1   0.001   3
21/12/2014  1   0.001   3
20/12/2014  1   0.001   3
19/12/2014  1   0.001   3
18/12/2014  1   0.001   3
17/12/2014  3   0.003   3
15/12/2014  2   0.002   4
14/12/2014  1   0.001   4
13/12/2014  1   0.002   4
```

Any help on the above problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), convert the 'date' to `Date` class, get the difference between adjacent element, check if that is not equal to 1, and do the `cumsum` to create the 'index' column.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, index:= cumsum(c(TRUE,abs(diff(as.Date(date, '%d-%m-%Y')))!=1))]
head(df1, 12)
#          date torn_count torn_dpi index
# 1: 31-12-2014          1    0.001     1
# 2: 28-12-2014          3    0.003     2
# 3: 27-12-2014          1    0.001     2
# 4: 22-12-2014          1    0.001     3
# 5: 21-12-2014          1    0.001     3
# 6: 20-12-2014          1    0.001     3
# 7: 19-12-2014          1    0.001     3
# 8: 18-12-2014          1    0.001     3
# 9: 17-12-2014          3    0.003     3
#10: 15-12-2014          2    0.002     4
#11: 14-12-2014          1    0.001     4
#12: 13-12-2014          1    0.002     4
```